# Using variables in command line command

Tags: matlab, cmd, command, line

I am having a problem in a batch file where my command isn't ran properly because it isn't using my set variable. My code is as follows:

```
set /p sNumber=Please enter your s-number:

set location = C:\Users\%sNumber%\Desktop\model\matlabFile.m

set

"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\matlab.exe" -r "run('%location%');"
```

This should run the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\matlab.exe" -r "run('C:\Users\hello\Desktop\model\matlabFile.m');"
```

If the entered sNumber were hello, but instead it tries, and fails, to execute the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\matlab.exe" -r "run('');"
```

Does anyone know how I can make this work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your path (the input to `run`) should be surrounded by single quotes since it's a string

Comment: That still results in the same issue where the variable doesn't seem to be used in the command.

Comment: Why do you have a lingering `set` after you set the location?

Comment: Because that prints all defined variables to the screen at that moment and I just wanted to see whether the location variable had been defined properly, and it has.

Comment: Maybe this isn't what's going on but try changing the set statement to `set "location=C:\Users\%sNumber%\Desktop\model\matlabFile.m"`.

Comment: Thankyou sir! That did work and did save us a lot of work!

Comment: Do *not* insert _spaces_ around the `=` sign in `set` assignments, because they become part of the variable name and the value; you are actually assigning a variable called `location` + _space_...

Comment: Thankyou, that was a practice from programming in PHP, JavaScript etc. now I know that isn't a good idea when coding for the Command Line :)